# How to use wkHTMLtoPDF with docker-compose and Django

Tags: django, docker-compose, wkhtmltopdf

I need help to understand how to use wkHTMLtoPDF with docker-compose and then apply it in Django. I tried to build docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: trytofindme
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8020:8080
  wkhtmltopdf:
    image: diegovieira/wkhtmltopdf:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/data
```

It was the first image of wkhtmltopdf, that I found and it was working. When I type `docker-compose up` - everything runs correctly, but at least i see that message: `server_wkhtmltopdf_1 exited with code 1`
Does someone know how to solve this problem? And then how to use it in Django. For example: I need to convert HTML to PDF simple page with text and need to save it in "../project-name/media/pdf.

I will be insanely grateful for your help.

Comment: did you find a solution to this in the meantime?